# Trouble with BitSet and String

Tags: java

So, I've been trying to convert a BitSet to a String representation (not the one given in the language), but something like "10010". My method works fine as long as there's a '1' between some zeroes, but if I entry something like "1000", the console just prints "1". I'm not a really great java coder, and so far I've learned by myself. I'd really appreciate the help TwT
Here's what I've done so far:

```
import java.util.BitSet;
public class Test_Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
   BitSet test=new BitSet();
   test.set(0);
   test.set(1,false);
   test.set(2,false);
   test.set(3,false);
   //test.set(4);
//       String S="1000";
//       BitSet test=Binary.toBitSet(S);

   String testString=Binary.toString(test);
   System.out.println("Result is:"+testString);
}

}
```

Here's the binary class I mention in the code:

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Binary {

//Returns a REAL string representation of a BitSet
public static String toString(BitSet B) {
    String reply = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length(); i++) {
        if (B.get(i) == true) {
            reply = reply + "1";
        } else {
            reply = reply + "0";
        }
    }
    return reply;
}

public static BitSet toBitSet(String S) {
    BitSet B = new BitSet(S.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
        if (S.charAt(i) == '1') {
            B.set(i);
        } else {
            B.set(i, false);
        }
    }
    return B;
}
}
```

When I run it:

```
run:
Result is:1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Notice that the BitSet I'm entering in "test" should be:"1000" but then again, zeroes won't appear unless there's a '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store somewhere the highest index you've set (i.e. the index until which you want to iterate), because BitSet doesn't keep that information. The javadoc of `length()` says:

> Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one.

(and "set bit", in this context, means "bit set to true").

You should also use a StringBuilder instead of using String concatenation: concatenating to a String in a loop makes a new String copy at each iteration, which is very inefficient for large BitSets.

Comment: Geez, I just realized that uwu Thank you very much mate! I don't really care a lot for efficiency right know, but I'll check out the StringBuilder. I just need to get this running for Friday. You know, college homework TwT Regards from Mexico! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest passing the an integer 'size' the the toString() method. BitSet doesn't know about bits that were set to 0, it infers the length from the highest set bit:

```
//Returns a REAL string representation of a BitSet
public static String toString(BitSet B, int size) {
    String reply = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (B.get(i) == true) {
            reply = reply + "1";
        } else {
            reply = reply + "0";
        }
    }
    return reply;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    BitSet test=new BitSet();
    test.set(0);
    test.set(1,false);
    test.set(2,false);
    test.set(3, false);
    //test.set(4);
    //       String S="1000";
    //       BitSet test=Binary.toBitSet(S);

    String testString=Binary.toString(test, 4);
    System.out.println("Result is:"+testString);
}
```

> The java.util.BitSet.length() method returns the "logical size" of
>   this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one.
>   Returns zero if the BitSet contains no set bits.
>   Check [the following link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/bitset_length.htm%20%22the%20following%20link)

Comment: Thanks for your help, pal! I really appreciate it :')